# Ordenar por quantidade propriedades com nomes diferentes em javascript

Tags: javascript

Suponhamos que eu tenha o seguinte array de objetos:

```
const funcionarios = [
{
    "id":0,
    "nome":"Marcelo",
    "sobrenome":"Silva",
    "salario":3200.00,
    "area":"SM"
},
{
    "id":1,
    "nome":"Washington",
    "sobrenome":"Ramos",
    "salario":2700.00,
    "area":"SM"
},
{
    "id":2,
    "nome":"Sergio",
    "sobrenome":"Pinheiro",
    "salario":2450.00,
    "area":"SD"
},
{
    "id":3,
    "nome":"Bernardo",
    "sobrenome":"Costa",
    "salario":3700.00,
    "area":"SM"
},
{
    "id":4,
    "nome":"Cleverton",
    "sobrenome":"Farias",
    "salario":2750.00,
    "area":"SD"
}
]
```

Preciso retornar qual a área com maior número de funcionários e a com menor número. Consegui contabilizar a quantidade de funcionários das áreas da seguinte maneira:

```
    let areasContadas = funcionarios.reduce( (todasAreas, areas)=>{
    if(areas.area in todasAreas){
        todasAreas[areas.area]++;
    }else {
        todasAreas[areas.area] = 1;
    }
    return todasAreas;
}, {})
```

Minha variável areasContadas agora vira um objeto com as propriedades "SM" e "SD" e a quantidade de funcionários em seus valores:

```
    areasContadas = {
    SM : 3,
    SD : 2
}
```

Agora como posso fazer para ordenar e distinguir qual área tem mais funcionários e qual tem menos, onde mesmo que eu adicione novas áreas o processo ainda seja funcional?

Comment: Como assim ordenar?

Comment: Em ordem crescente ou decrescente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como reordenar propriedades de objetos JavaScript. O que você pode fazer é usar o método `.sort()` para criar uma array ordenada e depois criar um novo objeto na ordem que você quer.

Veja o comentário de um usuário no SOen [numa pergunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1069666/1377664) à sua:

> "A ordem das propriedades do objeto não é padrão no ECMAScript. Você
>   nunca deve fazer suposições sobre a ordem dos elementos em um objeto
>   JavaScript. Um objeto é uma coleção não ordenada de propriedades. As
>   respostas abaixo mostram como 'usar' propriedades classificadas,
>   usando a ajuda de matrizes, mas nunca alterando a ordem das
>   propriedades dos próprios objetos. Então, não, não é possível. Mesmo
>   se você criar um objeto com propriedades predefinidas, não é garantido
>   que eles sejam exibidos na mesma ordem no futuro."

Por exemplo, o seu código retorna um objeto `areasContadas` assim:

```
{SM: 3, SD: 2}
```

Para ordenar do menor valor para o maior usando `.sort()`, resultará numa array assim:

```
['SD', 'SM']
```

À partir dessa array você pode criar um novo objeto assim:

```
{SD: 2, SM: 3} // do menor para o maior
```

Da mesma forma você pode criar um objeto com a ordem inversa.

No exemplo abaixo acrescentei mais objetos na array com 5 chaves `XX` para ilustrar melhor a ordenação:

Veja:

```js
const funcionarios = [
{
    "id":0,
    "nome":"Marcelo",
    "sobrenome":"Silva",
    "salario":3200.00,
    "area":"SM"
},
{
    "id":1,
    "nome":"Washington",
    "sobrenome":"Ramos",
    "salario":2700.00,
    "area":"SM"
},
{
    "id":2,
    "nome":"Sergio",
    "sobrenome":"Pinheiro",
    "salario":2450.00,
    "area":"SD"
},
{
    "id":3,
    "nome":"Bernardo",
    "sobrenome":"Costa",
    "salario":3700.00,
    "area":"SM"
},
{
    "id":4,
    "nome":"Cleverton",
    "sobrenome":"Farias",
    "salario":2750.00,
    "area":"SD"
},
{
    "id":4,
    "nome":"Cleverton",
    "sobrenome":"Farias",
    "salario":2750.00,
    "area":"XX"
},
{
    "id":4,
    "nome":"Cleverton",
    "sobrenome":"Farias",
    "salario":2750.00,
    "area":"XX"
},
{
    "id":4,
    "nome":"Cleverton",
    "sobrenome":"Farias",
    "salario":2750.00,
    "area":"XX"
},
{
    "id":4,
    "nome":"Cleverton",
    "sobrenome":"Farias",
    "salario":2750.00,
    "area":"XX"
},
{
    "id":4,
    "nome":"Cleverton",
    "sobrenome":"Farias",
    "salario":2750.00,
    "area":"XX"
}
]

let areasContadas = funcionarios.reduce( (todasAreas, areas)=>{
    if(areas.area in todasAreas){
        todasAreas[areas.area]++;
    }else {
        todasAreas[areas.area] = 1;
    }
    return todasAreas;
}, {})

console.log("Sem ordenação:", areasContadas);

const oMenor = Object.keys(areasContadas).sort(function(a,b){return areasContadas[a]-areasContadas[b]})
const menor = {};

oMenor.forEach(function(i){
   menor[i] = areasContadas[i];
});
console.log("Ordenado pelo menor:", menor);

const oMaior = Object.keys(areasContadas).sort(function(a,b){return areasContadas[b]-areasContadas[a]})
const maior = {};

oMaior.forEach(function(i){
   maior[i] = areasContadas[i];
});
console.log("Ordenado pelo maior:", maior);
```